# RavenDb license for NServiceBus

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus, nservicebus5

I'm using NServiceBus in my application, and since NServiceBus 5 RavenDb is not the default persistence and is not installed with NServiceBus. So I downloaded RavenDB-Build-2952 and installed with Development option on setup.

When I tried running my project (which still uses NServiceBus 4) I got an error that the license for RavenDb is not valid for windows authentication. There are not special configuration in my NServiceBus code regarding persistence of RavenDb.

How can I make sure that RaveDb installation uses the NServiceBus license?

Comment: I removed my answer because you're right, it is not relevant for v5. I believe you can either contact Particular and ask them to send you the license file, or install v4 with RavenDb and get the license.xml file from there as described in the documentation http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/using-ravendb-in-nservicebus-installing

Comment: the problem is that I can't find the NServiceBus v4 installation - all that's available for download is version 5.

Comment: I found that it is still available on Chocolatey https://chocolatey.org/packages/nservicebus.ravendb.install

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is an error, and not a warning?

I had this problem a few months ago, and even though this message appeared in the log, the system functioned without issue.

Try ignoring the error/warning (I'm assuming you're debugging), and see if persistence still functions as needed?

Comment: Yes. it threw an exception.

Comment: And if you ignore the exception, the bus fails to process messages?

Comment: Please contact support at particular.net for a license file